# Include a less file and pass parameters

Tags: less

I have a `common.less` file, that implements the basic CSS for different skins:

```
@textColor: black;
@iconSize: 16px;

.container: {
    color: @textColor;
    background-color: white;
}
.icon: {
    width: @iconSize;
    height: @iconSize;
}
// note that @iconSize is also used in this file inside mixins
```

The plan is to use it like so `skin_1.less`:

```
@iconSize: 32px; // override the icon size
                 // but leave @textColor as default
@import "common.less";

.container: {
    color: red;
}
// I would now have big icons and red text
```

So I would like to have a common style, that I can reuse and selectively override variables.

This does not ssem to work however. I think it's because imports are always moved to the top, so variables cannot be pre-defined.
(I also read that variables are rather constants, so that may be another problem.)

Anyway: is there a better pattern to solve my use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split the files up, just override the variable after the import. Variables are always resolved as the last definition, even if it is after where it is used.

Comment: ahh, I am beginning to understand the concepts. Somewhat counter-intuitive to me at the first glance. Thanks a lot!